# A stand-alone application that collect data from an IP and monitor them to the end user can be called "a web-based software"?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I created a MATLAB GUI that ables to collect data form an IP and monitor them to the end user. I packaged this GUI by MATLAB Development Tool and i'm using this stand-alone software. Can this software be called a "web-based software"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, a "[web-based software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application)" means a software that has a web user interface done with HTML and CSS. So the answer would be no because the software you created doesn't have a web user interface.

Your software would more likely be named a stand-alone application.